# kerberos: kadmin interface not working

Tags: kerberos

We are using kerberos for authentication with pam module. We need to reinstall kerberos on another machine. So , I took kerberos dump and planned to restore using it.

```
kdb5_util  -sf stash   load kdc.dump
```

After that , I can able to access `kadmin.local` interface. `list_princs` is working fine and all my users are listed in that and `kinit` also working fine. But If I am access `kadmin -p root/admin` i got below error.

**Error Log**

```
AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 127.0.0.1: SERVER_NOT_FOUND: root/admin@ULTRASOUND.ZMEDIA.COM for kadmin/bharathi.ultrasound.zmedia.com@ULTRASOUND.ZMEDIA.COM, Server not found in Kerberos database
```

Answer (score 1):

I shudder at the use of a `root/admin` principal.  You should really be using `<username>/admin`. However, that's not what's actually causing you trouble.

Your new `kdc` doesn't have a `kadmin/bharathi.ultrasound.zmedia.com@ULTRASOUND.ZMEDIA.COM` principal in its database. It never need to exist before as `kadmind` never ran on that host before.

You'll have to add the principal in via `kadmin.local`.

```
kadmin.local -q "addprinc -randkey kadmin/bharathi.ultrasound.zmedia.com@ULTRASOUND.ZMEDIA.COM
```